# App rejeitada por causa do Identificador de Propaganda (IDFA)

Tags: ios

Meu app não faz uso de nenhum tipo de propaganda, e mesmo depois de marcar "◉ Não" nas duas opções continuo recebendo um aviso abaixo e não consigo enviar o app para avaliação. O que pode estar acontecendo?

> [...] Se o seu aplicativo contém o IDFA e você selecionar Não, o binário será permanentemente rejeitado [...]

[image: mensagem mostrada]

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/apples-latest-crackdown-apps-pulling-the-advertising-identifier-but-not-showing-ads-are-being-rejected-from-app-store/

Comment: Galera, o binario ta certo!! Ta tudo ok da minha parte! O erro é da pagina que nao esta carregando corretamente! Existe uma 3ª opcao que ainda precisa ser selecionada! Vou trazer o link para a solucao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que aconteceu foi: a página que mostrei na imagem estava com problema de carregamento, ela na verdade possui 3 opções e não duas.

Portanto devido a esse erro de carregamento não permitia concluir o preenchimento das opções, e portanto, impedia do botão "enviar" ficasse disponível!

Nesse mesmo dia outros desenvolvedores que conheço tiveram esse mesmo problema.  No dia seguinte a Apple corrigiu a página e consegui postar meu app normalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Já tive um problema deste tipo por causa do Google Analytics, se for o seu caso, você precisa remover o iAd.framework e o libAdIdAccess.a do seu projeto, você deve manter a libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a para que o GA continue funcionando. Feito isso, faz um build, ve se ta tudo ok e sobe pra loja.

Sobre o motivo dessa pergunta que a Apple faz antes de subir seu produto, é que o iAd tem um recurso para identificar devices, o que implica na privacidade do usuário. Então a Apple só permite usar este recurso para apps que de fato fazem uso do iAd para seguimentar conteudo (como midia, banners, etc), sem infligir as normas de privacidade que você como desenvolvedor se comprometeu a não quebrar :)

Espero que ajude.